# How to bind to a ViewModel Property from Application.Resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

I would like to bind to a Property `ShowHat` which is within a `ViewModel` called "HatViewModel" from `Application.Resources`.

I can obtain access to the `ViewModel` via a namespace like so:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:HatApp.ViewModels
<Application.Resources>
<vm:HatViewModel x:Key="HatVM"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

But when I try to use the ViewModel's Property in a binding, it does not work.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HatVM.ShowHat}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Source` when you trying to bind a property from a static resource:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowHat, Source={StaticResource HatVM}}" Value="True">
```